# Bootstrap tooltip causing buttons to jump

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, tooltip

When I hover over a button and the tooltip appears, the buttons jump. If I disable the tooltip, it does not jump.  Additionally, the right button loses the rounded edges.  How can I prevent this from happening?

```
<div class="btn-group">
    <a rel="tooltip" class="btn" href="#" data-title="View Details"><i class="icon-list-alt"></i></a>
    <a rel="tooltip" class="btn" href="#" data-title="Delete"><i class="icon-trash">    </i></a>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip();
```

Working version...

http://jsfiddle.net/BA4zM/147/

Here is a website that has it working without the jumping...

http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB005S479

Comment: You are not alone with this one. Have you found a solution? Thanks?

Comment: It is fixed in version 2.3.0 of the bootstrap-tooltip.js file.  You can see it working here: http://jsfiddle.net/BA4zM/149/

Comment: @bmorehokie none of both works now....

Answer (score 154):

To avoid the jump, you need to set the container attribute. This is documented.

> When using tooltips and popovers with the Bootstrap input groups,
>   you'll have to set the container option to avoid
>   unwanted side effects.

Try the following:

```
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
```

Comment: If you need to also use `selector` for the case where new elements with tooltips can be added to the page on the fly, then, you'll need to set the `container` via a data attribute.  `data-container="body"`

Comment: hi @Howdie ! thanx for the solution, but, i still am curious, what exactly happens on btn-group, during tooltip ?

Comment: @DeepakYadav, it seems, tooltip container is inserted to the closest descendant element, by default, this contents of container affects the layout of buttons and button groups. Specifying explicitly the `body` container resolves the issue.

Comment: In a bootstrap dialog don't use body but modal-dialog

data-container=".modal-dialog"

otherwise the tooltip will not show up

Answer (score 2):

As Howie said at https://stackoverflow.com/a/14770263/7598367, it's necesary to add the 'container' to tooltip.

That didn't solve my issue (I had the same problem), it's also necesary to declare at JS file **BEFORE** the .tooltip() initilization, this way:

```
$('[data-toggle=tooltip]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Hope this helps if somebody has the same problem in the future.

Comment: This works now... super strange