# Tooltip button moving when hover

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Hover any button and you will see that it's moving by itself.
Why is this happening, is it a bootstrap bug?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="navbar-header" style="padding:4px 0 0 15px;">
  <button id="btnCadastrar" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Cadastrar">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span>
  </button>
  <button id="btnEditar" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Editar" style="margin-right:1px;">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
  </button>
  <button id="btnRemover" type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-danger btn-sm" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Remover">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
  </button>
</div>
```

**Bootply:**
http://www.bootply.com/iYnzOb5GY4

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Bootstrap tooltip causing buttons to jump](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364079/bootstrap-tooltip-causing-buttons-to-jump)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> #### Tooltips in button groups and input groups require special setting
>
> When using tooltips on elements within a `.btn-group` or an
>   `.input-group`, you'll have to specify the option `container: 'body'`
>   (documented below) to avoid unwanted side effects (such as the element
>   growing wider and/or losing its rounded corners when the tooltip is
>   triggered).

– [Bootstrap Explanation for Tooltips](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips)

Here what you need to change in your code

**JS**

```
$('[rel=tooltip]').tooltip({container: 'body'});
```

**HTML**

Add this attribute to your buttons

`data-container="body"`

Here is Bootply link

[Example](http://www.bootply.com/IshpWZj0eU)